# Customize the ringtone of notifications of a telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I was wondering if it was possible to set an alarm ringtone to notifications of a particular bot.
In the sense, I wish that as soon as a user received a notification from a telegram bot created by me, he would leave instead of the default notification ringtone, a personalized one from me (for example a siren alarm).
Do you think there is a way? because I've already done some research on the internet and haven't found anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, with the official Telegram clients, you can't change the notification sound.